# The AutoRoute does not change when the state changes

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, auto-route

For routing, I use `auto_route` and added listening to changes through the provider `reevaluateListenable: authProvider` but when my provider value changes, nothing happens, why doesn’t listening to changes work and they don’t open another page?

**main**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<AuthProvider>(
      builder: (context, authProvider, child) {
        return MaterialApp.router(
          theme: darkTheme,
          routerConfig: _appRouter.config(
            reevaluateListenable: authProvider,
            navigatorObservers: () => [
              TalkerRouteObserver(
                GetIt.I<Talker>(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

**authguard**

```
class AuthGuard extends AutoRouteGuard {
  @override
  void onNavigation(NavigationResolver resolver, StackRouter router) async {
    final AuthProvider appState = AuthProvider();

    if (appState.isLoggedIn) {
      resolver.next(true);
    } else {
      resolver.redirect(const AuthRoute());
    }
  }
}
```

**authprovider**

```
class AuthProvider extends ChangeNotifier implements Listenable {
  bool _isLoggedIn = false;

  bool get isLoggedIn => _isLoggedIn;

  void login() {
    _isLoggedIn = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void logout() {
    _isLoggedIn = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**loginscreen**

```
void onPressedMethod(bool isRegister) {
    final authProvider = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false);
    if (isRegister) {
      authProvider.login();
    } else {
      authProvider.login();
    }
  }
```